# How to query database using saxon sql:query where db.id='value of xml attribute'

Tags: sql, xslt, saxon

I have a requirement where i need to query database using saxon sql;query by applying where clause, where database_table.ProductID should match with incoming xml input productId

Here is what i tried so far:

```
<sql:query connection="$sql.conn" table="table_name" column="Product_ID" row-tag="row" column-tag="col" where="Product_ID="<xsl:value-of select="ProductItem/ProductItemId/text()"/>"" />
```

I am getting following Exception:

SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: Element type "sql:query" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

I am finding it difficult to format the where clause in XPath, can any one suggest what would be correct format. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use to use an attribute value template where you put the XPath expression in curly braces `{...}`, as in

```
<sql:query connection="$sql.conn" table="table_name" column="Product_ID" row-tag="row" column-tag="col" where="Product_ID=&quot;{ProductItem/ProductItemId}&quot;"/>
```

Comment: The other approach that's sometimes useful is to use a variable: `<xsl:variable name="query">Product_ID="<xsl:value-of select="ProductItem/ProductItemId"/>"</xsl:variable>` then `<sql:query query="{$query}"/>`

Comment: What will be in the case of where based on 2 values: suppose

Comment: where="PRODUCT_ID={ProductItem/ProductItemId} and ACT_ACTION={ProductItem/ProductActionCode} is giving me (SQL) ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: @Michael thanks for the advice, i tried it: <xsl:variable name="query">
  Product_ID="<xsl:value-of select="ProductItem/ProductItemId"/>"
   ACT_ACTION="<xsl:value-of select="ProductItem/ProductActionCode"/>"
  </xsl:variable>  for which i was getting <Parameter name="ACT_CODE1" value="ACT_CODE_1145ACT_CODE_1159ACT_CODE_1163"/> i.e i have 3 rows in database and it is returning me all 3 act_code, where as i require specific one.

Comment: I found the solution for the above "missing expression" by using &apos; but i will still require your solution @MichaelKay as i would like to see which way would be better.

Comment: I've completely lost track of the thread. If you have solved the original problem but have hit another problem, then open a new question and describe the new problem from first principles.